# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)) - `find' and `create' for RoR app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Thanks for any help you can provide! I've reviewed other topics related to this error but haven't been able to find a solution for my situation.

I've got an HTML form and two MYSQL database tables for my Ruby on Rails app. My first table has "masterlocations": points of interests with nicknames, IDs, and addresses. The form lets the user select a "masterlocation" by its nickname from a drop-down. My second table, newsavedmap, saves the masterlocation that the user selects.

My goal is to:

1. See if the masterlocation nickname selected in the dropdown matches the nickname of any of the masterlocations in my masterlocation database.
2. If so, I want to save the masterlocations's ID to @newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id.

I think I'm almost there, but I'm getting the "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1))" with my current code.

**Controller**

```
    def create

@newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new(params[:newsavedmap])
@masterlocation = Masterlocation.all
@newsavedmap.name = params[:newsavedmapname]

if !params[:starthere].blank?
  @newsavedmap.start = params[:starthere]
else
  @newsavedmap.start = params[:startthere]
  @newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id = @masterlocation.find(params[:id], :conditions => {:nickname => params[:startthere]})
end

if !params[:endhere].blank?
  @newsavedmap.end = params[:endhere]
else
  @newsavedmap.end = params[:endthere]
end

if !params[:waypointsselected].blank?
  @waypoint = Waypoint.new(params[:waypoint])
  @waypoint.waypoint = params[:waypointsselected]
  @waypoint.newsavedmap = @newsavedmap
end


respond_to do |format|
  if @newsavedmap.save
   # flash[:notice] = 'The new map was successfully created.'
   # format.html { redirect_to "/itineraries/#{@newsavedmap.itinerary_id}#showmaps" }
    format.html { redirect_to "/maptry" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @newsavedmap, :status => :created, :location => @newsavedmap }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @newsavedmap.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  if @waypoint.save
   # flash[:notice] = 'The new map was successfully created.'
   # format.html { redirect_to "/itineraries/#{@newsavedmap.itinerary_id}#showmaps" }
    format.html { redirect_to "/maptry" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @waypoint, :status => :created, :location => @waypoint }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @waypoint.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end

end
end
```

**ERROR CODE**

Occurs in the line for @newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id = @masterlocation.find(params[:id], :conditions => {:nickname => params[:startthere]})

```
    ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
    app/controllers/newsavedmaps_controller.rb:66:in `find'
    app/controllers/newsavedmaps_controller.rb:66:in `create'
```

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to vinodadhikary, I've added the Masterlocation line below, but I updated it with => and a colon. However, the ID is not being saved to the database. Instead, the record's field updates with

```
    --- []
```

CODE

```
    def create

@newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new(params[:newsavedmap])
@newsavedmap.name = params[:newsavedmapname]

if !params[:starthere].blank?
  @newsavedmap.start = params[:starthere]
else
  @newsavedmap.start = params[:startthere]
  @newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id = Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => { :id => params[:id], :nickname => params[:startthere]})

end
```

Comment: Please edit your question summary to add more context, an error code is hardly enough. Also add more info about the error code (backtrace, line...).

Comment: Just added some additional info on the error. Please let me know if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points to note here.  The `Masterlocation.all` returns an `Array` and when you do `Array.find()` then that in turn returns `Enumerator`.

You can check these by testing the following in your `rails console`:

```
@masterlocation.class
=> Array

@masterlocation.find().class
=> Enumerator
```

So the `#find` method method only takes in one parameter(Ref doc: http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Enumerable#find-instance_method) and you are trying to supply two, hence the error.

The fix for this would be to do:

```
@masterlocation.find{|ml| ml.id == params[:id] and ml.nickname == params[:startthere]}
```

But then the question is why do you want to retrieve all the `Masterlocation`s and then use `find` on the ruby side instead of in the database via ActiveRecords as follows?

```
Masterlocation.find(:all, conditions: { :id => params[:id], :nickname => params[:startthere]})
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see my update. is it possible there are some syntax issues in your reply?

Comment: @KDP, there shouldn't be any syntax errors as I tested these.  The only thing I would double check for is the field names like `id` which I assume you haven't changed.  Aside from that the only problem I see in your code is you are assigning the return value to `@newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id`, that statement returns an `Array` so if you are sure that condition matches one and only one record then you could do `Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => { :id => params[:id], :nickname => params[:startthere]}).first.id`.  Try that.

Comment: Hmm. When I do `@newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id = Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => { :id => params[:id], :nickname => params[:startthere]}).first.id` , a number is being saved. However, it's not the ID of the Masterlocation. Any way to save the ID instead?

Comment: @KDP, when you say it's not the ID of the Masterlocation, what do you mean?  Could you explain that a little further?

Comment: Sure! I'm trying to make `@newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id` equal to the ID of the Masterlocation whose nickname matches params[:startthere]. For some reason, `@newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id` is not being saved as the ID of the Masterlocation. It's always the number 4 for some reason. How can I make the value that is saved the ID of the Masterlocation whose nickname matches params [:startthere]?

Comment: Maybe the number 4 is constant because it represents the number of fields that I have in the `newsavedmap` record or something. I'm just trying to save the ID of the Masterlocation.

Comment: @KDP, check the value of `Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => { :id => params[:id], :nickname => params[:startthere]}).first.inspect`.  You could use `Rails.logger.debug` to see if the result contains the value you need.

Comment: Hmm. Database saves the value as nil

Comment: @KDP, can you initiate a chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34885/discussion-between-kdp-and-vinodadhikary)